# How do I use multiple arguments in a mips assembly function?

Tags: function, debugging, assembly, mips

I am reading in two integers, the first must be between 1 and 7. The second must be between 1 and 7, and not less than the first. To check these number I am using a function and then returning either 1 or 0, which will repeat the input in a loop until a valid input is given.

Here is my problem: The first number seems to go in well, and it loops until a valid input is given. However for my second function, it's pretty much the same but I am using two arguments (`$a0` for the first number and `$a1` for the second). Whenever I run the program on QTSpim, it freezes immediately after entering the second integer. Can anyone help me?

Here is my code:

```
main:
    li      $v0,5
    syscall

    move    $a0,$v0
    jal     checkdiv

    move    $s0,$a0
    slt     $t0,$zero,$v1
    beq     $t0,$zero,NE
    j       main

    NE: 
    li $v0,5
    syscall

    move    $a0,$v0
    move    $a1,$s0
    jal     checknum


#These are the two check functions 

checkdiv: 
    addiu $sp,$sp,-8
    sw      $ra,4($sp)
    sw      $a0,0($sp)

    li      $t0,1
    slt     $v1,$a0,$t0
    beq     $v1,$t0,D1

    li      $t0,7
    slt     $v1,$t0,$a0
    D1:
    lw      $ra,4($sp)
    lw      $a0,0($sp)
    addiu   $sp,$sp,8
    jr      $ra

#Second check function

checknum: 
    addiu $sp,$sp,-16
    sw      $ra,8($sp)
    sw      $a0,4($sp)
    sw      $a1,0($sp)

    slt     $v1,$a0,$a1
    li      $t0,1
    beq     $v1,$t0,N1
    li      $t0,7
    slt     $v1,$t0,$a0
    N1:     lw $ra,8($sp)
    lw      $a0,4($sp)
    lw      $a1,0($sp)
    addiu   $sp,$sp,16
    jr      $ra
```

Comment: `checknum` will eventually return, and at that point execution continues at the instruction directly after the `jal`, which right now is the first instruction of `checkdiv`.

Comment: https://www.lri.fr/~de/QtSpim-Tutorial.pdf Check "debugging".